# How to test a JavaScript-based application, for example Ember.js with Selenium 2?

Tags: javascript, selenium, ember.js, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I have created a JavaScript-based application, powered by Ember.js framework. Now, I'd like to create Selenium 2 tests for the application. However, I have encountered the following problem:

The test is supposed to interact with the button or input field not present on the page by default. In other words, there is an Ember.js view which is displayed only after a certain action. Anyway, when I perform the action and enter the desired view.

Then, I want to click to the button in test, such as follows (Selenium 2 test is in PHP):

```
$button = $this->byId("myButton");
$button->click();
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Is this because Ember.js (or any other JavaScript tool) inserts the code dynamically? I tried to sleep for a second or two before performing the click action, it did not help.

How can I solve this issue and test JavaScript client-side app (written in Ember.js in my case) with Selenium 2?

Comment: So if you perform the action that is supposed to show the view with the button and then wait, even 10, 60 seconds before performing the click, you still get the same message?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Well, I didn't try 60 seconds, but even 10 sedonds do not help. And the view renders below 1 second for sure.

Comment: So when you run your code you can clearly see the button show up and then after the sleep times out and the code tries to click on `myButton` then you get the error you pasted? Is this site publicly available for access btw?

Comment: Yes, you got the point. The tested application is quite complex so I won't paste it, but it renders the button in an ordinary Handlebars template. The test suite is simple, looks as follows: https://gist.github.com/pavelsmolka/5612920  
The button is certainly found, because the suite does not throw an error on the first line. It says the error only when a click is attempted - with the informatino the button is not visible.

Comment: What driver are you using? I used Phantom.js (0.90) and I didn't managed to get elements added by Ajax calls. It worked well with Chrome Driver, didn't test with the default Firefox Driver.